# What are the differences between TrackMania Nations Forever and TrackMania² Stadium?

Tags: trackmania-2, trackmania-forever

A few days ago I've purchased TrackMania² Stadium on Steam. I'm really enjoying it, even though I'm not that good. After also trying the (free) TrackMania Nations Forever, I've been wondering what the differences are between these two games.

The only differences I've found so far:

- Improved graphics
- A number of different tracks
- The ability to build underground in the track editor

Are there any other differences?

Comment: when you say "number of different tracks" do you mean "enviroments?" Nations Forever only has the Staduim enviroment.

Comment: Both games only have the stadium environment, but they have different courses within those environments.

Comment: Different leaderboards, that's all I can think of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrackMania Nations Forever is a free version of Trackmania. I originally purchased the United Forever title in which you would receive more environments. The games themselves are Identical.

Trackmania 2 Stadium features all that you mentioned over its predecessor as well as an improved track editor and improved leader boards.

Essentially $5 (December Steam Sale 2013) gets you an upgraded Environment and editor with their version of a workshop where users my buy/sell/trade tracks, car designs (and more?).

Comment: Interesting why Trackmania 2 Stadium is much cheaper than Trackmania United Forever?

Answer (score 1):

I found another distinguishing feature: Trackmania 2 now has support for the Oculus Rift DK2, while the older versions only support color filter 3d glasses. It's definitely one of the more demanding VR experiences in terms of motion sickness though...